# Creating a MySQL market basket analysis

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, market-basket-analysis

For the final project of my data class, I'm attempting to create a market basket analysis in MySQL (using Workbench 6.3 CE and Server 5.7) from a database of 900,000-plus transactions.

Here is the sketch of a table I've put together to get me what I need (some of the stuff is for later queries)...

**Table:**

```
sales
```

**Columns:**

```
pos_trans_id INT(11) 
basketId VARCHAR(45) 
productNumber VARCHAR(25) 
productDescription VARCHAR(255) 
categoryCode VARCHAR(25) 
categoryDescription VARCHAR(255) 
subcategoryCode VARCHAR(25) 
subcategoryDescription VARCHAR(255) 
quantity INT(11) 
purchaseAmt DECIMAL(12,2) 
dateOfSale INT(11)
```

---

This is the query I whipped together to try to make my own version of a market basket analysis:

```
SELECT purchaseone.productNumber, purchaseone.productDescription, purchasetwo.productNumber, purchasetwo.productDescription, purchaseone.basketId
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT productNumber, productDescription, basketId
    FROM sales) AS purchaseone
        JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT productNumber, productDescription, basketId
        FROM sales) AS purchasetwo
        ON 
        (
            purchaseone.basketId = purchasetwo.basketId AND
            purchaseone.productNumber != purchasetwo.productNumber AND
            purchaseone.productNumber < purchasetwo.productNumber
            );
```

Problem I'm running into is the query will run for hours and hours and hours and give me nothing in the end, or it'll take so long to visualize in Workbench that it's useless.

Does anybody have any idea if I'm doing something wrong here or if there's something I should to to speed things up? Thanks in advance.

*Edit: Here's the extra context you asked for. *

Full [raw data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1H6hfMLFzhdPN4RIr83zn6jD1fJVn1zmu)

Two custom tables I've created so far:

`` CREATE TABLE `sales` 
    (\n  `pos_trans_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\',
    \n  `basketId` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `productNumber` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `productDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `categoryCode` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `categoryDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT \'0\',
    \n  `subcategoryCode` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `subcategoryDescription` varchar(255) DEFAULT \'0\',
    \n  `quantity` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `purchaseAmt` decimal(12,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `dateOfSale` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
    \n)
    ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ``

`` CREATE TABLE 'date' 
    (\n `dateKey` int(11) NOT NULL,
    \n  `dayOfTheMonth` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  `dayOfTheWeek` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    \n  PRIMARY KEY (`dateKey`)
    \n) 
    \n ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ``

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server. Please don't tag irrelevant RDBMS, and it's important you know which one you're using. I've removed the tag for you. :)

Comment: noted. thanks. sorry.

Comment: Have you tried to rework your query so that you don't have that many _nested_ queries in there? Avoiding _nested_ queries can help you improve performance because sub-queries tend to be run more frequently than what you may be thinking, and often to produce a similar result that could've been cached in some way.

Comment: Also, consider checking the [official MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/) to get a better understanding of what your query is really doing, performance implications of the `DISTINCT` keyword, and so on.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big tables and analysis in MySql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794232/big-tables-and-analysis-in-mysql)

Comment: This should and can be written using simple joins without the sub-queries. If that isn't fast enough, then run EXPLAIN on the query to see if you have the proper indexes on the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your query, it appears you are trying to produce a "also purchased" or "purchased with" type of analysis.
The query below should run significantly faster. It eliminates the sub-queries in your query and simplifies the task quite a bit.

```
SELECT 
    a.productNumber, 
    a.productDescription, 
    b.productNumber, 
    b.productDescription, 
    a.basketId
FROM `purchaseone` a
LEFT JOIN `purchaseone` b
ON a.basketId = b.basketId AND
    a.productNumber != b.productNumber AND
    a.productNumber < b.productNumber
GROUP BY a.basketId, a.productNumber, b.productNumber
```

Comment: Will point out `purchaseone` here should actually be `sales` in both cases.


Giving this query a shot now

Comment: Just curious. How long did this query take to run?

Comment: Around 8 1/2 hours.

Comment: Have you run explain on the query? That should indicate what indexes are being used, and where indexes might be used to improve the execution speed. If you post the results from an explain in your question, that would help.